# Change Value of First Bit in Binary String - Java

Tags: java, genetic-algorithm

I have a program which works with genetic algorithms and generates an 8-bit binary string (chromosome consisting of eight genes).

I would like to know how I would go about **changing** / **flipping** the first gene/bit.

For example:

```
Original chromosome:
01010101

Changed chromosome:
11010101 //First bit has been changed
```

If the first bit has a value of `1`, I would like to 'flip' it to make it a `0`; and, obviously, if the first bit in the array/chromosome is a `0`, I would like to 'flip' that to a `1`.

Thank you.

Comment: Your assertion '8 bit binary string' is misleading. Are you storing this data in an int, short, or as a String?

Comment: The data is stored in an `int`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the following:

```
chromosome ^= 0x80;
```

The xor-assignment (`^=`) flips the `chromosome` bits that are set in the right-hand side expression, and `0x80` is `10000000` in binary.

More generally, to flip the `k`-th bit (with the least significant bit being bit 0):

```
chromosome ^= (1 << k);
```